# PhoneCredential must be valid phone credential

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Hi i'm trying to set the phone number of a User with my following method and I get the following error "updatePhoneNumber failed: First argument "phoneCredential" must be a valid phone credential." I have tried different ways any suggestions?

```
_addPhone = ()  =>{
firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber({
  phoneNumber: '+441234567890' // Fake for question 
}).then(function(userRecord) {
  // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
  console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
})
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error updating user:", error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled phone authentification in your firebase console?

Comment: Yes but I use another service to verify (twilio) I just want to set it after my verification

Comment: I think you need to use `linkWithPhoneNumber` rather than `updatePhoneNumber`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46763427/5508175 https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/70slpi/can_you_update_phonenumber_from_userprofile/

Comment: `linkWithPhoneNumber` this uses the application verifier thats why i'm not using the firebase phone number auth from the start it's not currently supported in expo

Comment: I know. I don’t think you can do it the way you are thinking.

Comment: [`updatePhoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePhoneNumber) accepts a phone credential. You are passing an invalid parameter.

Comment: @bojeil can you give me an example a correct value to pass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updatePhoneNumber` method can only accept valid credentials that firebase will create once a phone number will be verified.

[Similar question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/q/46763427/5508175)