# How to use email and phone to authentication in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am looking for a way in react-native to make user sign up with his phone number then add his email and password.
But when a user logs in, he logs in only with email and password.

The phone number is only for security reasons.

I do a signInWithPhoneNumber() after user verify his number i call a createUserWithEmailAndPassword() but that's made in console Auth Two separate authentication in the same time 
"Email" & "Phone Number"

[image: Auth]

code

```
// I just pass the result into separate screen then use it to confirm all stuff is work :D

...
auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneWithAreaCode, true)
        .then(confirmResult => {
          console.log('2', phoneWithAreaCode);
          console.log('confirmResult', confirmResult);
          this.setState({
            confirmResult,
            loading: false,
          });
        })
...

confirmCode = codeInput => {
    const {confirmResult, email, password} = this.state;
    console.log('codeInput Is:', codeInput.length);
    if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
      confirmResult
        .confirm(codeInput)
        .then(async () => {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
          const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
          await auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(({user}) => {
              console.log('hey u');
              let uid = user.uid;
              params.createUser(uid);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Handle Errors here.
              var errorCode = error.code;
              switch (errorCode) {
                case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                  this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
                  break;
                case 'auth/invalid-email':
                  this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
                  break;
                case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
                  this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
                  break;
                case 'auth/weak-password':
                  this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
                  break;
                default:
                  this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
                  break;
              }
            });
          //Check if any users exist
          // database()
          //   .ref(`users`)
          //   .limitToFirst(1)
          //   .once('value', async snapshot => {
          //     if (snapshot.exists()) {
          //       console.log('exists!');
          //       return true;
          //     } else {
          //       // params.createUser(user.uid);
          //       console.log('No user found Hah');
          //     }
          //   });
          this.setState({
            timer: 0,
            isValid: true,
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          let errorCode = error.code;
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);
          switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
              this.setState({codeInput: ''});
              this.refs.codeInputRef2.clear();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Not here');
    }
  };
```

### EDIT

```
 confirmCode = codeInput => {
    const {confirmResult, password, email} = this.state;
    console.log('codeInput Is:', codeInput.length);
    if (confirmResult && codeInput.length) {
      confirmResult
        .confirm(codeInput)
        .then(user => {
          console.log(user);
          let userE = auth().currentUser;
          // userE.updateEmail(email); 

          auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

          clearInterval(this.interval);
          const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
          params.createUser(user.uid);
          this.setState({
            timer: 0,
            isValid: true,
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          let errorCode = error.code;
          let errorMessage = error.message;
          switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
              this.refs.codeInputRef2.clear();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Not here');
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hey dude @Dupocas why you delete firebase-auth Tags? my question relate in them

Comment: Only removed react-native since it doesn't directly relate to it. Thanks for warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use multiple auth providers for the same user, then you need to link them to prevent creating separate users. To link them you can use `linkWithCredential()` for example:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

Here you pass the email and password to the `EmailAuthProvider.credential` method, then you can pass the `AuthCredential` object to the signed-in user's `linkWithCredential` method:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then(function(usercred) {
  var user = usercred.user;
  console.log("Account linking success", user);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Account linking error", error);
});
```

You can check the docs for other ways to link multiple providers :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account

Comment: That's Great, But i will say the scenario to insure if that's will help or not, I have a 3 screens ("splash, signup, Home") in a splash screen i make a listener onAuthStateChanged if logged i navigate hem to Home else to sign up, now in sign up i use createUserWithEmailAndPassword() and in then() statement i use verify phone number but onAuthStateChange() don't let me do that because it's directly Navigate me to Home so what you think?

Comment: In sign up add both phone number and email and link them. Then if user is already logged in they will go to home screen directly. So when u sign up do both phone and email

Comment: "but onAuthStateChange() don't let me do that because it's directly Navigate me to Home so what you think?" yes because user is already logged in... When u first sign up add both phone and email and link them then there shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Can you edit your answer to achieve both the phone and email?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763427/firebase-phone-authentication-and-linking

Comment: Have you checked the link

Comment: yes... I'm working with it right now, just another question I release my app for stores but I can't get the SMS code to verify on my phone number although I added SHA-1 to my app settings in firebase console have any idea about that?

Comment: I couldn't have any solutions for these So I just use signInPhoneNumber() and it's work fine, and when i confirm the code i just update the email so i get an email and phone number in one uid like here https://imgur.com/fhW0tq7,

 But when i use sendPasswordResetEmail() to this email i got "auth/user-not-found" although it's appeared in Auth console, SO i think in another way to do it with createUserWithEmailAndPassword() after verification BUT it's not helping me , it just makes two separate users like here https://imgur.com/f0JS7zI 

So how can i use it to refer in one user "uid"

Comment: Why were you not able to link the auth provider? The link that I provided is the same as your question

Comment: I think you see it in room discussion  I check the link and do as he writes
but i got this error

erorr Error: firebase.auth.User.linkWithPhoneNumber() is unsupported by the native Firebase SDKs.

Comment: FYI I use react-native-firebase I think it's not supported LinkWithPhoneNumber sadly, is any way to solve it?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203273/discussion-between-oliver-d-and-peter-haddad

Comment: can you check the chat, please?

Comment: Hello @PeterHaddad How can i track error code & message at `linkWithCredential` when i use to catch and log error code i got `errorCode => auth/unknown` What's unknown why i see it